# Cannot find new threads: generic error

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

When I try to debug my C++ application using gdb, I get the following error:
`[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Cannot find new threads: generic error`

If I try to quit gdb, I get `A debugging session is active. Inferior 1 [process 17785] will be killed.`

I am not using any thread library myself.

I tried the solutions suggested in [gdb: Cannot find new threads: generic error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702628/gdb-cannot-find-new-threads-generic-error) but did not help.

My OS: Ubuntu 10.04

```
$ gcc -v 
(Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)
$ uname -a
Linux rskDesktop 2.6.32-33-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 21:07:13 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not using any thread library myself

Take a look at this answer: [reverse-step multithread error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625486/reverse-step-multithread-error/6625735#6625735) which should apply in your situation: force GDB not to activate thread debugging if you don't want it to be aware of the threads.

(the EDIT applies as well, but maybe it's one of the libraries you use which requires the `libpthread.so`)