# Cannot find new threads: generic error 64bit Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb

I know that there are a few topics around this subject, however none of them helped me.

I am trying to debug my application using GDB and I am obtaining the error

```
 [debug]Cannot find new threads: generic error 
 [debug][Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
```

in the function dlopen("my_lib.so", RTLD_LAZY);

The strange fact about this is that it used to work before, when I was compiling under Ubuntu of 32bit architecture. Now, I have moved to a new machine, with 64bit ubuntu installed, **HOWEVER**, I am giving the compile option -m32 so that the application is still compiled under 32bits. Please don't tell me to try to compile it under 64bit because there are several reasons not to do so.

I have followed the instructions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702628/gdb-cannot-find-new-threads-generic-error) topic and still nothing.

Does anybody have a different suggestion?

**EDIT:** The version of GCC on 32bit machine is 4.4.4 and GDB is 7.2
On the 64bit machine the version of GCC is 4.6.1 and GDB is 7.3

May this have any influence?

Comment: Have you tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Comment: I just downgraded the version of GCC from 4.6 to 4.4 and it started to work perfectly. I really don't get what's going on on.

Answer (score 0):

Please setup this

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 gdb --args ./app
```

Comment: I have said in my post that I've read some related posts and none of them helped. In your case I just get: ERROR: ld.so: object '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

So that's why i was wondering how to work arround this